# moveItemAtPath. No errors, but not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

Im trying to move files. Below I'm testing if the paths exist. They do, however both    copyItemAtPath and moveItemAtPath don't seem to work.

```
NSString *testUrl = @"/Users/justinshulman/Documents/test2";
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:testUrl]) {
    NSLog(@"yes");
}
NSString *testUrl2 = @"/Users/justinshulman/Documents/test1";
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:testUrl2]) {
    NSLog(@"yes");
}
NSLog(@"%@",testUrl);
NSLog(@"%@",testUrl2);
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:testUrl2 toPath:testUrl error:nil];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]moveItemAtPath:testUrl2 toPath:testUrl error:nil];
```

Answer (score 5):

That is exactly your problem, both move and copy will not actually overwrite the destination file if it already exists. You'll have to remove it first and then copy (or move) the other file to that URL.

Try with

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:testUrl error:nil];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:testUrl2 toPath:testUrl error:nil];
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: Remove a file that you are going to move, first?  Isn't that the other way around?

Comment: I'm simply making sure that *if* there was a file at the testUrl location, it is removed before copying over the new file (which is what the OP was asking for)

Answer (score 1):

You should also be checking for the error instead of passing nil.

```
NSError* error = nil;

[[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:testUrl2 toPath:testUrl error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
   NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

It also returns a bool on whether the copy was successful.

Adding to @micantox answer, always read the class reference.  See [class reference for NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtPath%3atoPath%3aerror%3a):

> If a file with the same name already exists at dstPath, this method
>   aborts the copy attempt and returns an appropriate error.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `NSError` object in error filed.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:testUrl2 toPath:testUrl error:&error];

Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 UserInfo=0x100457e80 "The operation couldn’t be completed.

[[NSFileManager defaultManager]moveItemAtPath:testUrl2 toPath:testUrl error:&error];

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 UserInfo=0x1004a2270
```

Use `replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:`

> Replaces the contents specified by the first URL with the contents of
>   the second URL in a manner that insures no data loss occurs.

Answer (score 0):

@justin, First thing it never works only. Because you are trying to copy the source path to destination path where both path are same. Second thing, how NSFileManager copy or move api works is, you have to copy or move source path to different destination path with appending your appropriate path component. For example see the code below:--

```
NSString *testUrl = @"/Users/home/Documents/source.rtf";
        //
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:testUrl]) {
            NSLog(@"yes");
        }
//Below destination is folder name which should be exist on your machine or else you can create programmatically as well 
        NSString *testUrl2 = @"/Users/home/Documents/destination";

        NSLog(@"%@",testUrl);
        NSLog(@"%@",testUrl2);
        NSError *err=nil;

    //Now we are copying the souce path to destination folder with appending file name (it can be any your name becuase file manager copy source file contents to your destination file contents)
    //Here given file name is a destination.rtf where you can give any your name. Also this is for copying source contents to destination contents

        NSFileManager *fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if ([fm copyItemAtPath:testUrl toPath:[testUrl2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"destination.rtf"] error:&err])
        {
            NSLog(@"success");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",[err localizedDescription]);
        }
```

Comment: Let me know, if still you  face any issue on this

Comment: Also you can write this line like that as well NSString *testUrl2 = @"/Users/home/Documents/destination/destination.rtf"; inspite of writing this stringByAppendingPathComponent code below in copying api. This is only for your understanding have mentioned.

Comment: Sorry in advance, really new at this. What i'm trying to do is create a program to move files or folders into a specified folder. Will what you've showed above accomplish this with modification or am i off track?

Comment: Yes the same thing you can do just use this moveItemAtPath inspite of using this copyItemAtPath

Comment: And one more thing if you want to move sub folder then don't add file extension otherwise it will create as file only give as a name wo file extension

Comment: What is the purpose stringByAppendingPathComponent? I need to change my files if i want to move them? Hmmm there must be a better way.

Comment: @justin my point is stringByAppendingPathComponent is used for mentioning your file name thats it.

Comment: And also you are not changing your destination files but else you can change the name of destination files while copying or moving source files

Comment: Eventhough you can put the same name as source files. Please let me know where you are facing issue to understand on this as it is very simple.