# NSFileManager moveItemAtPath does not work

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfilemanager

I am using https://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_file_handling.htm as a reference to move a file to another directory but it is not working. There is no error. I added the code to see if it could find the file and it can, but when I am using moveItemAtPath it does not seem to work.

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //Get documents directory
    NSArray *directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"/Users/SAMPLE/folder1/file.txt"] == YES) {
        NSLog(@"File exists");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"DNE");
    }
    
    NSError* error = nil;

    if([fileManager moveItemAtPath:@"/Users/SAMPLE/folder1/file.txt"
       toPath:@"/Users/SAMPLE/folder2/" error:&error]) {
          NSLog(@"Moved successfully");
    }
    else if (error != nil) {
       NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

I checked to see what the error is with code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19244978/12486838 and the error message I get is

> “file.txt” couldn’t be moved to “SAMPLE” because an item with the
> same name already exists.

Why is it just stopping at Users/? Why is it comparing the second folder in the file path?

I have also tried to change `toPath:@"/Users/SAMPLE/folder2/"` to `toPath:@"/Users/SAMPLE/folder2/file.txt"` and the error message is

> “file.txt” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “folder2”.

What kind of permission would I need?

Comment: Please read [moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1413529-moveitematpath?language=objc) "dstPath:
The new path for the item in srcPath. This path must include the name of the file or directory in its new location.".

Comment: Is the app sandboxed?